# Python sort list of dictionary using another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my data

```
pricing = [
    {
      "link": "https://www.kohls.com/product/prd-3751773/laura-geller-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick.jsp?skuid=75792684",
      "price": "21",
      "stock": true,
      "title": "Laura Geller Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick, Red Overfl",
      "seller": "Kohl's"
    },
    {
      "link": "https://www.macys.com/shop/product/laura-geller-beauty-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-cream?ID=5713197&PartnerID=LINKSHARE&cm_mmc=LINKSHARE-_-4-_-41-_-MP441",
      "price": "21.00",
      "stock": true,
      "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
      "seller": "Macy's"
    },
            {
      "link": "https://www.macys.com/shop/product/laura-geller-beauty-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-cream?ID=5713197&PartnerID=LINKSHARE&cm_mmc=LINKSHARE-_-4-_-41-_-MP441",
      "price": "21.00",
      "stock": true,
      "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
      "seller": "Wal-Mart.com"
    }
  ]
```

Below code i am writing make them sort as per the list

```
retailers = ["Amazon", "Wal-Mart.com", "Target", "CVS",  "Walgreens","Macy’s", "Nordstrom", "MassGenie", "Kohl's", "Kmart"]
data = sorted(pricing, key=lambda x: retailers.index(x['seller']))
```

error:

```
ValueError at /api/product/
"Macy's" is not in list
```

Here i am trying to sort data by **seller** key as per the list **retailers** but, i am getting key error while sorting the data. Please have a look where i am making mistake

I am expecting result:

```
pricing = [
    {
      "link": "https://www.macys.com/shop/product/laura-geller-beauty-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-cream?ID=5713197&PartnerID=LINKSHARE&cm_mmc=LINKSHARE-_-4-_-41-_-MP441",
      "price": "21.00",
      "stock": true,
      "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
      "seller": "Wal-Mart.com"
    },
    {
      "link": "https://www.macys.com/shop/product/laura-geller-beauty-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-cream?ID=5713197&PartnerID=LINKSHARE&cm_mmc=LINKSHARE-_-4-_-41-_-MP441",
      "price": "21.00",
      "stock": true,
      "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
      "seller": "Macy's"
    },
    {
      "link": "https://www.kohls.com/product/prd-3751773/laura-geller-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick.jsp?skuid=75792684",
      "price": "21",
      "stock": true,
      "title": "Laura Geller Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick, Red Overfl",
      "seller": "Kohl's"
    }
  ]
```

Please have a look

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. The problem is `"Macy’s"` is not the same as `"Macy's"` (note the different apostrophe character).

Comment: change the. data in retailer's list to reflect the same as dictionary

Comment: Just change `’` to `'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `retailers` list shows this way:

```
  retailers = ["Amazon", "Wal-Mart.com", "Target", "CVS",  "Walgreens","Macy’s", "Nordstrom", "MassGenie", "Kohl's", "Kmart"]
```

Change it to

```
  retailers = ["Amazon", "Wal-Mart.com", "Target", "CVS",  "Walgreens","Macy's", "Nordstrom", "MassGenie", "Kohl's", "Kmart"]
```

All I did was to change `’` to `'`

Btw, `Kohl's` looks correct

Answer (score 0):

**There where 2 errors in your code**

1. `macy’s` in `retailers` list. **instead of** `macy's`
2. `true` in `pricing` list. **instead of** `True` (Boolean starts with capital Letter in python)